# Mapbox Hover with React

Tags: reactjs, mapbox, mapbox-gl

I am having trouble getting the hover functionality to work with mapbox using React JS.

This code is taken from the Mapbox documentation found here [Mapbox Documentation hover](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/hover-styles/) and I have just substituted in my data.

My code is the following and there is a snippet of the JSON data below that.

I have set up a sandbox environment here -[Hover Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-breeze-vqbg2s?file=/src/App.js)

```
        mapboxgl.accessToken =
      "pk.eyJ1IjoicGJyb2NrbWFubiIsImEiOiJjajgxbnlqbGg2enR4MnhxbXllaHYzOGNzIn0.mA9mk90HM6ePh0gQq_55yw";
    
    const HoverMap = () => {
      const mapContainer = useRef();
      const [map, setMap] = useState(undefined);
      const zoom = 12.2;
    
      useEffect(() => {
        // Creating the map
        setMap(
          new mapboxgl.Map({
            container: mapContainer.current,
            style: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v12",
            center: [151.89, -33.830348],
            zoom: 7,
          })
        );
      }, []);
    
let hoveredStateId = null;
      useEffect(() => {
        if (typeof map === "undefined") return;
        map.on("load", () => {
          map.addSource("RandwickCityCouncil", {
            type: "geojson",
            data: RandwickCC,
          });
          map.addLayer({
            id: "RandwickCityCouncil-fills",
            type: "fill",
            source: "RandwickCityCouncil",
            layout: {},
            paint: {
              "fill-color": "#627BC1",
              "fill-opacity": [
                "case",
                ["boolean", ["feature-state", "hover"], false],
                1,
                0.2,
              ],
            },
          });
          map.addLayer({
            id: "RandwickCityCouncil-outline",
            type: "line",
            source: "RandwickCityCouncil",
            layout: {},
            paint: {
              "line-color": "#f50202",
              "line-width": 2,
            },
          });
    
          
    
          // Hover effect
    
          map.on("mousemove", "RandwickCityCouncil-fills", (e) => {
            if (e.features.length > 0) {
              if (hoveredStateId !== null) {
                map.setFeatureState(
                  { source: "RandwickCityCouncil", id: hoveredStateId },
                  { hover: false }
                );
              }
              hoveredStateId = e.features[0].id;
              map.setFeatureState(
                { source: "RandwickCityCouncil", id: hoveredStateId },
                { hover: true }
              );
            }
          });
    
          map.on("mouseleave", "RandwickCityCouncil-fills", () => {
            if (hoveredStateId !== null) {
              map.setFeatureState(
                { source: "RandwickCityCouncil", id: hoveredStateId },
                { hover: false }
              );
            }
            hoveredStateId = null;
          });
        });
      }, [map]);
    
      return (
        <div>
          {/* <MapToolbar> Map Toolbar </MapToolbar> */}
          <div className="mapbox" ref={mapContainer} />
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default HoverMap;
```

The map renders and displays the opaque fill (0.2) but when I hover with the mouse it doesn't transition to a fill of (1).

My JSON data looks like this.

```
    {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "name": "RandwickCityCouncil",
  "crs": {
    "type": "name",
    "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4283" }
  },
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "csId": "RCC-20221116103310",
        "cadid": "108012496",
        "lganame": "RANDWICK",
        "councilnam": "RANDWICK CITY COUNCIL",
        "abscode": 6550.0,
        "supplydate": "2022-11-16"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "MultiPolygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              [151.237223263119546, -33.890750241364117],
              [151.237312069267318, -33.890752670602645],
              [151.237401162262444, -33.890752374791312],
              [151.237490291113488, -33.890749344966139],
              [151.237579204829018, -33.890743625947039],
              [151.237667643453619, -33.890735199806031],....
```